# What happened to Peter Quill at the end of Guardians of the Galaxy 2

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

I must say that I was kinda disappointed when it turned out in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2, that

> Star-Lord has powers.

Now, I'm pretty sure that it was addressed in the movie, but I can't exactly remember.

**Does Peter still have those at the end of the movie?**

Comment: Also asked on Science Fiction and Fantasy: [What is Peter Quill's status after Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/159041/70236)

Comment: Should be like in Doctor Strange (because same cinematic universe). Peter will find a way to bring it back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of the movie, as the core of the planet is destroyed, Ego claims that this will prevent Peter from using his abilities, and indicates that it will make him "just like everyone else". We can also see Peter's abilities fade.

> Ego: "Listen to me! You are a god! If you kill me, you'll be just like everybody else!"
>
> Peter: "What's so wrong with that?"
>
> Ego: "No!"

However, as this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159041/what-is-peter-quills-status-after-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2) points out, Ego might have been lying and Peter might just need to find another power source or re-learn his powers.

Comment: My answer there pointed out much the same, although I came at it from a narrative angle. There's plenty of material there for future writers to give him as much or as little future power as they might find helpful for story purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> **Does Peter still have [powers] at the end of the movie?**

#### No.

Peter Quill / Star-Lord lost his powers in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*. James Gunn, the director of the *Guardians of the Galaxy* movies, confirmed this in a [tweet that he posted](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/1655346696593997824) after the release of *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023), where Peter was not shown using the powers he inherited from Ego in *Vol. 2*.

[image: Screenshot of James Gunn's tweet]

> Does peter still have some kind of power or something unnatural in his body that makes him Survive more than a normal human???

> **James Gunn:** No.